# memory leak using CFBundleCopyResourceURL

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks

Instruments tells me, that I'm leaking memory with the following lines of code

```
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle ();
    CFStringRef aString =CFStringCreateWithFormat(NULL, NULL, CFSTR("%i"),aNumber);                    
    sound= CFBundleCopyResourceURL (mainBundle, aString, CFSTR ("aiff"), NULL);
    CFRelease(aString);
```

I do release sound - which is of course a CFURLRef - in the dealloc of this class (which by the way is a subclass of UIView) using CFRelease.

The culprits seem to be a NSURL and a NSCFString.

But what else can I do apart from releasing sound and aString?

Comment: Try using the breakpoints to see if it really goes to dealloc and alloc and how many times it does. This is a guess considering that maybe you have other views and it is being reloaded.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That wasn't it, but your suggestion it put me on the right track:

In addition to setting a breakpoint I logged the contents of "sound" while deallocating: In certain circumstances I change its value, and hadn't thought of releasing the old value first. Now everything works as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use breakpoints to interact with the variable in question, that way you will likely solve your problem.